# subprocess check_output throw exception when redirect stderr to /dev/null and called by multiprocessing.map_async

Tags: python, subprocess, python-multiprocessing

Consider this code:

```
#!/usr/bin/python                                                               

import os                                                                       
import multiprocessing                                                          
import subprocess                                                               

def search(name):                                                               
    devnull=open(os.devnull, 'w')                                               
    res = subprocess.check_output(                                              
            ['sleep', name]                                                     
            #, stderr=devnull # works fine when comment out                                                  
            )                                                                   

class Manager(object):                                                          
    def __init__(self):                                             
        self.pool = multiprocessing.Pool(4)                                     

    def clean(self):                                                            
        self.pool.close()                                                       
        self.pool.join()                                                        

    def fetch(self, names):                                                     
        res = self.pool.map_async(search, names)                                
        return res.get(10)                                                      


if __name__ ==  '__main__':                                                                                                              
    manager = Manager()                                                       
    manager.fetch([1, 2, 3])                                                    
    manager.clean()
```

If I change stderr to point to a temporary file or not changing stderr at all, the code will execute fine, otherwise I get the following exception:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./z.py", line 71, in <module>
    manager.fetch([1, 2, 3])
  File "./z.py", line 64, in fetch
    return res.get(10)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/multiprocessing/pool.py", line 554, in get
    raise self._value
TypeError: execv() arg 2 must contain only strings
```

Can anyone please explain why?

Comment: As for the exception - on my OS it happens with or without the file output. What OS do you use?

Comment: it can't work whether `stderr` present or not. Command line arguments must be strings, not integers. Check `type(name)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As suggested by the exception, your problem is in `execv()`, which is actually used by `subprocess.check_output` to run the arguments. It tells you that the array of argument *must* be string. You'll get the same error for the following code:

```
devnull=open(os.devnull, 'w') 
subprocess.check_output(["sleep", 1], stderr=devnull)
```

**The solution is quite simple** - change `manager.fetch([1, 2, 3])` to `manager.fetch(["1", "2", "3"])`.